# Get list of recently listened music

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone app that needs to retrieve and manipulate information about the songs played on the device.

I know it is possible to get the song that is currently playing using `MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong`.

However, what I really need is to have access to a list of recently played tracks.

`MediaHistory` and `MediaHistoryItem` classes don't seem to provide this.

Is is really possible? How?

Comment: Is it possible to record the ActiveSong to create your own history? You should be able to create a list of recently played songs from it.

Comment: Nope. My app can't run all the time in order to record every song played on the device. I need to get songs that were played even when my app was not executing.

Comment: @vitorsdcs Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.aspx and perhaps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743066(v=vs.85).aspx As far as I can tell getting the recently played songs isn't possible unless the player keeps track by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current API, as @Igor has pointed out in his answer does not allow this. However, there is another way for us to reasonably assume that a particular media file has been played recently, by getting some information about the actual file.

We can use `GetBasicPropertiesAsync()` along with `RetrievePropertiesAsync()` which will give us the `DateAccessed` property for that file.

Here is a code snippet taken from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.aspx) MSDN page:

```
public async void test()
{

    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("Filepath");
        if (file != null)
        {
            StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();

            // Get basic properties
            BasicProperties basicProperties = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            outputText.AppendLine("File size: " + basicProperties.Size + " bytes");
            outputText.AppendLine("Date modified: " + basicProperties.DateModified);

            // Specify more properties to retrieve
            string dateAccessedProperty = "System.DateAccessed";
            string fileOwnerProperty = "System.FileOwner";
            List<string> propertiesName = new List<string>();
            propertiesName.Add(dateAccessedProperty);
            propertiesName.Add(fileOwnerProperty);

            // Get the specified properties through StorageFile.Properties
            IDictionary<string, object> extraProperties = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(propertiesName);
            var propValue = extraProperties[dateAccessedProperty];
            if (propValue != null)
            {
                outputText.AppendLine("Date accessed: " + propValue);
            }
            propValue = extraProperties[fileOwnerProperty];
            if (propValue != null)
            {
                outputText.AppendLine("File owner: " + propValue);
            }
        }
    }
    // Handle errors with catch blocks
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        // For example, handle a file not found error
    }
}
```

Once you have the `DateAccessed` property in a variable, we can see if it is a recent date, say, yesterday, or maybe even 2 or 3 days ago. Then we'll know that if it's been accessed within a short period of time, it could have been played.

There are some caveats to this, though. Some virus scanners change the Timestamp properties on files and folders, and they also need to open files to scan them which I would assume would change the `DateAccessed` property. However, many new Antivirus apps that I've seen revert the Timestamp info back to the original, as if it had never touched the file.

I believe this is the best workaround for this problem at the moment. *Unless* you only care about when *your* app recently played a file. Then the answer to that question is as simple as you managing your own recently-played lists for media files.

## Update

---

In order to retrieve the `PlayCount` for a specified song, you can access that song using the `MediaLibrary` class:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
```

Then just access the song like this:

```
Int32 playCount = library.Songs[0].PlayCount;
```

where `[0]` is the index of the song you'd like to get the PlayCount for. An easier way (depending on how you're accessing songs already, might be to do something like:

```
Int32 playCount = library.Artists[selectedArtistIndex].Albums[selectedArtistAlbumIndex].Songs[selectedSongInAlbumIndex].PlayCount;
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need. However, there is no way to know how many times the media file was played, right?

Comment: @vitorsdcs Sure. But in order to do that you'll need to keep track of that yourself, unfortunately. Basically, you can create a settings file when the user opens your app for the very first time, then you can manage your media files that way. So, when the user starts playing media with your app, you add 1 to the PlayedCount setting for that file, then the next time you load up your app, read back that play count and show it to the user, if you get what I mean?

Comment: I am having a look at an old project of mine to confirm what I just said. I have a feeling there may be something in the MediaPlayer class you can use (maybe).

Comment: @vitorsdcs I will update my answer to include a bit of code so you can get the PlayCount using the built in MediaPlayer classes.

Comment: @vitorsdcs Done. Updated answer to include code to get `PlayCount`. As an alternative to the code in my answer, you could also use `Int32 playCount = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.PlayCount;` to get the PlayCount.

Comment: Great. My app won't play any media, it will only have to use this info to display some statistics to the user. So when my app is launched for the first time, I can create a settings file to record the current playCount for each song in the library. The next time it is launched, I can check for recently played songs using DataAccessed, then check if the playCount for these songs have changed by comparing it to the settings file that I had previously created. This seems to work for me.

Comment: @vitorsdcs Awesome. Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with the current API. MediaHistoryItem only returns last item set by your application, so it is of no use.

Comment: Not even a workaround? I just saw that Xbox Music is now showing a list of recently played albums (I'm using WP 8.1). Isn't this type of info available for other apps?

Comment: Xbox Music is an app made by Microsoft, they can use APIs that we cannot